# How to run TeX4ht and or tex4ebook

Tags: conversion, scripts, epub

I have found that I can use tex4ebook to convert my Latex document into Epub3 but I haven't found anywhere where it states what program should be used to run the script (I normally write Latex in Overleaf).

I would like to run the following: tex4ebook -f epub3 filename.tex mathml

Thanks in advance

Comment: For running `tex4ebook` on Overleaf see https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/testing-tex4ebook-to-generate-basic-epubs/fdthzgghvbcd. The standard way to do this however is to install a local version of LaTeX on your own computer (MikTeX for Windows, MacTeX for Mac, TeX Live for Linux), and then run the command you mention in your question in the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: the program is just tex4ebook, if you have a local tex installation you can simply type the line you show to the command line. On overleaf You may be able to get latexmk to run it, but the online interface is not ideal for accessing the genarated files

Comment: In addition to what @Marijn and David said, you can also use Github Actions with Overleaf, as described in [this example](https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html). You would need to modify the command in the YAML file to use `tex4ebook` instead of `make4ht`. Your Epub file could be then downloaded from the web.